# Is there a way to add the same image into a ImageView again and again?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Suppose i need to add a same image to an imageView to get a pattern, same like a scale thing where i have first section but need to repeat it 10 more times.

How should i go for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use 10 UIImageView instances that all point to the same image, rather than trying to cram them into a single image view.  Or you could go down a level and use a Quartz pattern: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_patterns/dq_patterns.html